# how to change chrome default hotkeys?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-frontend

i just want to change or disable chrome default hotkeys cause other app conflicted with chrome default hotkey(option+cmd+right arrow).

i have tried some chrome plugins like 「Shortkeys」「Disable keyboard shortkeys」but not work.

so is there anyway to change chrome default hotkeys?

version: 100.0.4896.75 (arm64) on MacOS 12.2.1

thanks.

Comment: No, you can not change behaviour of browser via JS

Comment: Does this help you? https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/10012893?hl=en